# Access row with previous non unique date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Date        Module      Lines  
0      2017-07-01  Engine      68312
1      2017-07-01  Game        20322
2      2017-07-01  Editor      34433
3      2017-07-02  Engine      68432
4      2017-07-02  Game        21401
5      2017-07-02  Editor      34431
```

I want to create a column that counts the difference in lines between a particular day and the previous day. So for the Engine Module the difference would be 120 on 2017-02-02.

I've looked at using the shift column for something like:

```
data["Lines Delta"] = data["Lines"] - data["Lines"].shift(1, "D")
```

But this doesn't work and I think it's because the date isn't the index. I can't make it the index because it's not unique.

I'm pretty unfamiliar with Pandas so I'm not sure how else to do it other than manually in a loop, which I'd rather not as it'd be quite slow.

Comment: @DavidColson, what's the format of "Dates" on your df? Is it datetime or string?

Comment: The "Lines" value on each row with Module == "Engine" subtracted from the same value on the previous day. So here it's 68432 - 68312

Comment: @LuanNaufal it's datetime not a string

Comment: Oh yes my mistake, 120, corrected now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you're just looking for `groupby` and `diff`, as long as you have an entry for each `Module` for each Date:

```
# if your dates aren't datetime to start with, uncomment:
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# and if your dates aren't sorted:
# df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)

df['delta'] = df.groupby('Module').Lines.diff()
>>> df
        Date  Module  Lines   delta
0 2017-07-01  Engine  68312     NaN
1 2017-07-01    Game  20322     NaN
2 2017-07-01  Editor  34433     NaN
3 2017-07-02  Engine  68432   120.0
4 2017-07-02    Game  21401  1079.0
5 2017-07-02  Editor  34431    -2.0
```

Comment: If the difference with the `n`th previous day was required, one could use `.diff(periods=n)`.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it only takes the diff with previous rows, disregarding the date itself, and I understood that @DavidColson is interested in checking the diff between one date and the previous one. 
But this solution doesn't work for unordered DF, even if you have an entry for each `Module` and for each `Date` (where the `delta` will always show the same value, disregarding the date it contains)

Comment: The `groupby` takes care of that, if there is one entry for each module for each day. If it's not sorted by date, then a simple `df.sort_values('Date')` takes care of it

Comment: you're right when it comes to use the `.sort_values('Date')` @sacul!
I suggest adding this to your answer, as in the question it's not specified that sorting is guaranteed, and indeed is a good point for other reading your answer